# Visual Studio 2013 testsettings: Pulling files from test agent

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, mstest

I have tests which create local files with results. Can I define in the .testsetting file to pull these result files from the test agent, once the tests are finished?

I know that copying files in the other direction is possible, that is

```
<TestSettings name="BAT-SOME-NAME" id="111111ce-f87a-22222-85b0-cea1111111">
  <Deployment>
     <DeploymentItem filename="..\bin\Release\x64\MyFile.xml" />
  </Deployment>
</TestSettings>
```

will copy `MyFile.xml` to the test agent before starting the tests. How can I define to pull `MyCustomOutput.xml` after the test are finished?

Answer (score 0):

The `.testsettings` file has a section for **set-up** and **clean-up** scripts, ie batch command or `.exe` files etc. You could put suitable remote copy command into the **clean-up** script.

Comment: This will work, but I want to make sure there isn't a simpler way, which is mstest-builtin. Isn't there anything equivalent to <Deployment> for copying files in the opposite direction?